# How to clean tf.dataset cache

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use tf.dataset in a loop where data generator is updating, and use cache() in memory for speed up. I notice that the memory of my process keeps increasing, and it's finally killed. Here is my pseudocode

```
data_generator = xxxx
for _ in range():
    data_generator.update()
    data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_generator).map().cache().xxx()
    model.fit(data)
```

I thought that variable 'data' will refer to a new dataset in the loop, so the older dataset will be collected by gc and memory is totally released. But it seems wrong. How could I clean the cache created by tf.dataset?

Comment: You can probably try [`tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator).

Comment: Thanks but actually the data object "is" generated from generator. Let me make the statement clearer.

Comment: Hi @JerryD, you could try using `tf.keras.backend.clear_session`, which resets all states generated by Keras. Please refer to this [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/clear_session) for more information. Thank you!